# Proof the Grassmannian is a local functor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, category-theory, grassmannian

The Grassmannian functor $\mathrm{Gr}_{n, r}$ sends a ring $A$ to the set of rank $n$ summands of the free module $A^{n + r}$.  This is a local functor and I.1.3.13 of Demazure and Gabriels book "Introduction to Algebraic Geometry and Algebraic Groups" supposedly contains a proof of this fact.

I've been staring at this proof for a week and I just can't parse it.  I would love if there was a second source that I could compare with but everything I've found deals with the Grassmannian as a locally ringed space, not a functor.  Does anyone know of a second source that deals with the Grassmannian as a functor?

Comment: [The Stack's Project typically does things like this.](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/089R)

Comment: Or Vakil's _FOAG_ (http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/index.html).

Comment: As far as I know Vakil does locally ringed spaces, not functors of $R$-algebras.  The stacks project does treat the Grassmannian as a functor, but out of schemes instead of $R$-algebras.  It does suggest a different way to define the Grassmannian (surjections instead of summands) and maybe with that viewpoint I'll have better success finding a proof on my own instead of parsing DG's proof.

Comment: You can adapt the Vakil's construction of Grassmannian functor to your case; that is, you can restrict your attention to affine schemes (over a commutative ring $R$ with unit), and you obtain a functor as you desire. Am I clear?

Comment: Yes, that does give me the functor I'm looking at, unfortunately the proof I'm looking for appears to be an exercise in Vakil's notes (16.7.A)